# Can I Simply Change A Transaction Log From Unrestricted to Restricted?

Tags: sql-server

I've got a database with a data file size of 674 MB and a transaction log of 6.1 GB. **The transaction log is about 10 times bigger than the data file.**
The transaction log settings can be seen in the image below.

[image]

The server is constantly running out of space and this transaction log takes up about 11% of the total disk space. I'd like to make this transaction log file smaller.

Can I simply just change the "Maximum file size" by switching to Restrict file growth [MB]: and set the size to say 80 MB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer restricting to unrestricted.

If some process goes awry, then I don't want the log file to grow and grow and fill the disk up. I'd rather the DB stopped working than the entire Server/SQL Server Instance.

However, in this case you have a different issue: most likely "FULL" recovery and no log backups. Change to simple, shrink the log to, say 500MB, allow growth at 250MB, set a maximum of 2GB.

Comment: and don't forget to add a log backup job.

Comment: There's no need for log backups using SIMPLE recovery.

Comment: true; i missed the change to simple part. how about add full backup job.

Answer (score 2):

It is not advisable to restrict the transaction log file growth, as that will interfere with the database's ability to record transactions.

If this is a non-production box, or you never plan on doing point-int-time recovery, you could switch the database recoveryoption  to "simple".  After every checkpoint the log will be automatically truncated, thus preventing growth (unless you are doing a crazy amount of work inside one transaction).

Set the database to simple mode, truncate the log, shrink the log, set auto-growth to 128MB, and you should be on your way.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you will not be able to reduce the size of the log files from the database `property window`. You may get an error message around the lines of: 'The new file size is currently smaller than the current file size...'. However you can try the following steps:

1. First put your DB recovery to simple mode: `ALTER DATABASE Your_DB_Name SET RECOVERY SIMPLE`.
2. Shrink the log file using `DBCC` or `SSMS`.
3. Set you desired file growth settings in the `database property` window.
4. Put the DB recovery back to full mode: `ALTER DATABASE Your_DB_Name SET RECOVERY FULL`.

As @gbn expressed, I also prefer putting the file under a restricted growth. If the file fills up the drive and you do not have any extra space, then you may not be able to shrink the file later on affecting all the DBs that have data/log files on the same drive.